# Amplify GraphQL DataStore : auth rules: groupsField being ignored

Tags: graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-appsync, datastore

I've been working on this a few days and can't seem to make a dent.    I'm trying to use dynamic groups auth with the DataStore but it's always syncing all records, regardless of group settings.   Maybe someone here knows a bit more about this that I'm missing.

Here's my model (simplifed)

```
type Thing @model @auth(rules: [
    { allow: groups, groupsField: "tenant" }
]) {
  id: ID!
  tenant: String @default(value: "admin")
}
```

I've made sure that the values in DynamoDB have the tenant set, and the cognito:groups field contains the tenant (String) but still it's pulling all of them even when I should not be able to see them.

Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

Well. this seems to have made a difference.  I was using an older version of datastore.  it wasn't even in my package.json so it was sucked in by some other dependency...

By upgrading to the latest datastore, things are working much more as expected.

```
"@aws-amplify/cli": "^11.0.3",
"@aws-amplify/core": "^5.1.8",
"@aws-amplify/datastore": "^4.1.7",
```

I'm still annoyed that this is being filtered on the frontend and not the backend, but there is an open "feature request" for that: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-swift/issues/1635